# TypeScript spawn errors

Tags: node.js, typescript, async-await

I'm porting some bash scripts to TypeScript. Most of them are sequential invocations of system utils like curl, tar, mkdir, etc...

It could be newbie errors, but need a help figuring out what's wrong with spawn/exec invocations in this one-file TypeScript code:

```
#!/sbin/ts-node

import * as child from 'child_process';
const { promisify } = require('util');

const exec = promisify(child.exec);

const basePkgDir = process.env.HOME + '/cross/pkg';
const baseTmpDir = process.env.HOME + '/cross/tmp';

class Formula {
    private pkgDir: string;
    private tmpDir: string;

    constructor(public name: string, public version: string, public url: string) {
        this.url = url.replace(/\${pkgver}/gi, version)

        const pkgName = name + '-' + version;
        this.pkgDir = basePkgDir + '/' + pkgName;
        this.tmpDir = basePkgDir + '/' + pkgName;
    }

    private async run(cmd: string) {
        await exec(cmd, {cwd: this.tmpDir}, (error: Error, stdout: string, stderr: string) => {
            console.log(stdout);    
            if (error)
                console.log(error);  
            if (stderr)
                console.log(stderr)
        });
    }

    private async createDirs() {
        this.run(`mkdir -p ${this.pkgDir}`);
        this.run(`mkdir -p ${this.tmpDir}`);
    }

    private async download() {
        this.run(`curl -LJO ${this.url}`);
    }

    public async process() {
        await this.createDirs();
        await this.download();
    }
}


async function main() {
    const xz = new Formula('xz', '5.2.3', 'https://github.com/xz-mirror/xz/archive/v${pkgver}.tar.gz');
    await xz.process();
}

main().then(
    text => {
        console.log('Done.');
    },
    err => {
        // Deal with the fact the chain failed
        console.log(err)
    }
);
```

Running the script gives these errors:

```
{ Error: spawn /bin/sh ENOENT
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:229:19)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:406:16)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:745:11)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/ts-node/src/bin.ts:147:12)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:689:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:700:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:599:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:538:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:530:3)
  errno: 'ENOENT',
  code: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'spawn /bin/sh',
  path: '/bin/sh',
  spawnargs: [ '-c', 'mkdir -p /home/alex/cross/pkg/xz-5.2.3' ],
  cmd: 'mkdir -p /home/alex/cross/pkg/xz-5.2.3' }

{ Error: spawn /bin/sh ENOENT
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:229:19)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:406:16)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:745:11)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/ts-node/src/bin.ts:147:12)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:689:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:700:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:599:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:538:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:530:3)
  errno: 'ENOENT',
  code: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'spawn /bin/sh',
  path: '/bin/sh',
  spawnargs: [ '-c', 'mkdir -p /home/alex/cross/pkg/xz-5.2.3' ],
  cmd: 'mkdir -p /home/alex/cross/pkg/xz-5.2.3' }
Done.

{ Error: spawn /bin/sh ENOENT
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:229:19)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:406:16)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:745:11)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/ts-node/src/bin.ts:147:12)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:689:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:700:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:599:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:538:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:530:3)
  errno: 'ENOENT',
  code: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'spawn /bin/sh',
  path: '/bin/sh',
  spawnargs:
   [ '-c',
     'curl -LJO https://github.com/xz-mirror/xz/archive/v5.2.3.tar.gz' ],
  cmd:
   'curl -LJO https://github.com/xz-mirror/xz/archive/v5.2.3.tar.gz' }
```

I suspect something is wrong with the way `async/await` or `promisify` are used here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out, the error is caused because your `cwd` does not exist.
Simply changing to `{cwd: '/'}` lets the program succeed at `createDirs()`.

See also https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/9644#issuecomment-281613121

---

I had the following changes made to make it work:

1) Changed shebang line `#!/usr/bin/env ts-node`
2) `tsconfig.json`

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "lib": [ "es2015" ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Got it, the reason was in `{cwd: this.tmpDir}` when `tmpDir` does not exist on the moment when command runs.

If there are any other potential errors or suggestions on async/await, exec/spawn - please shoot.